# Python Flask TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-session

Please could someone help, other similar questions have been of no use thus far.

I am serving a Python3 Flask server that has been working fine for a while now.

I just started implementing a virtual environment and did all the pip installs, but my app crashed with the following Traceback when I try to run the app withing the venv, and normally:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2095, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2080, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    ctx.push()
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask\ctx.py", line 434, in push
    self.session = session_interface.open_session(self.app, self.request)
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_session\sessions.py", line 344, in open_session
    data = self.cache.get(self.key_prefix + sid)
  File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cachelib\file.py", line 194, in get
    if pickle_time == 0 or pickle_time >= time():
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

The error is thrown when I try to get the session data.

So I am uncertain whether it is the venv that broke this, or now something with my machine, because I rolledback on my git versions, and even pip uninstalled some of the recent imports.

Here is the Flask initializer and the first 2 functions:

```
from flask import Flask, request, session
from flask_session import Session
from functools import wraps
from datetime import timedelta
from json import dumps
from rest.api import api, users_api, setups_api, reports
import os
import shutil


# App Instance
app = Flask(__name__)
project_path = os.path.abspath('.')
app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = project_path
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_PATH'] = project_path + "/cookies/"
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
Session(app)


@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(hours=(5))
    if request.path not in ["/api/login", "/api/get-session-data"]:
        if not session.get('user'):
            return "Sign in needed.", 403


@app.route("/api/login", methods=["POST", ])
def login():
    # login things
    session['user'] = "whatever"
    return dumps("")


@app.route("/api/get-session-data")
def give_session_data():
    session_data = {
        "user": session.get("user")
    }
    return dumps(session_data)
```

Venv requirements are:

```
bcrypt==3.2.0
cachelib==0.6.0
cffi==1.15.0
click==8.1.2
colorama==0.4.4
cryptography==36.0.2
cycler==0.11.0
distlib==0.3.4
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
filelock==3.7.1
Flask==2.1.1
Flask-Session==0.4.0
fonttools==4.33.3
greenlet==1.1.2
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.1
kiwisolver==1.4.3
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
matplotlib==3.5.2
mysql-connector-python==8.0.28
mysqlclient==2.1.0
numpy==1.22.4
openpyxl==3.0.9
packaging==21.3
pandas==1.4.2
paramiko==2.10.3
Pillow==9.0.1
platformdirs==2.5.2
protobuf==3.20.0
psycopg2==2.9.3
pycparser==2.21
pycryptodome==3.14.1
PyJWT==2.4.0
PyNaCl==1.5.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
PyPDF2==1.27.3
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.1
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.37
virtualenv==20.14.1
Werkzeug==2.1.0
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: looking at the error it seems pickle_time is None. Checking out a **newer** version of /cachelib/file.py (https://github.com/pallets-eco/cachelib/blob/c48bb7ea79549b4e3cadb6622ab5170e313b95af/src/cachelib/file.py#L204) ```pickle_time = struct.unpack("I", f.read(4))[0]``` it looks like struct.unpack returns None. It should only return a tuple. Maybe have a look at 'get' in your version of file.py to see why pickle_time is None?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah it seems "lib\site-packages\cachelib\file.py" is a python file out of my codebase. How do I check if there is some python update that could rectify this?

Comment: Just noticed ```C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cachelib\file.py``` doesn't look like it's actually in a venv... are you sure you are running venv correctly? I use pipenv on Linux so could be wrong. As for updates read the venv docs - one use of venv is to keep dependencies in sync so updating just one could break things

Comment: Just checked your version (0.6.0) if file.py and None is returned from ```pickle_time = self.serializer.load(f)``` so checked self.serialiser in /cachelib/serialisers.py  - None is returned on pickle error ```def load(self, f: _t.BinaryIO) -> _t.Any:
        try:
            data = pickle.load(f)
        except pickle.PickleError as e:
            self._warn(e)
            return None
        else:
            return data``` so if you dig into the reason pickle throws an error it may help

Comment: Yeah that error was when I ran it from my pc normally.
The venv error was the same, just with a different path.
But I found a solution that I will post in the answers...
Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I wasn't able to actually find out what went wrong.

Turns out the solution was to uninstall Python (version 3) on Windows and reinstall it again.